# Exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException', Unable to cast object of type 'MS.Internal.NamedObject' to type 'System.Data.DataRowView'

Tags: c#, wpf

Code at front end:

```
<ListView Name="lvCus" MouseDoubleClick="ListViewItem_DoubleClick">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="true" ColumnHeaderToolTip="TbCus">
            <GridViewColumn Header="CusID" Width="40" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=CusID}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Firstname" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=fn}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Lastname" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ln}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Dob" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=dob}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Age" Width="60" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=age}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Below is the code at backend:

```
private void ListViewItem_DoubleClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   System.Data.DataRowView cusObj = (System.Data.DataRowView)lvCus.SelectedItem;
   var myobj = cusObj.Row.ItemArray;
   txtCusID.Text = myobj[0].ToString();    
   txtfn.Text = myobj[1].ToString();
   txtln.Text = myobj[2].ToString();
   txtdob.Text = myobj[3].ToString();
   txtage.Text = myobj[4].ToString();
}
```

ListView is loaded with data, and it seems to have one empty row at the end. When i click on empty row of ListView, i got following error:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in WpfApp.exe
>
> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'MS.Internal.NamedObject' to type 'System.Data.DataRowView'.
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

I got above error, how can i resolve that? Guys, I am in learning phase.

Comment: Can you not add a Null check to your selected item ? It's probably because of attempting a cast on a Null item.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @Tim: Definitely i want some solution to get rid of error, that is why posted  the error.

Comment: @PrageethSaravanan: i got exception before null check. Can you give me example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the as operator to make sure that the SelectedItem property actually returns a System.Data.DataRowView in order to avoid getting an exception when the user double clicks on the last row:

```
    private void ListViewItem_DoubleClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Data.DataRowView cusObj = lvCus.SelectedItem as System.Data.DataRowView;
        if (cusObj != null)
        {
            var myobj = cusObj.Row.ItemArray;
            txtCusID.Text = myobj[0].ToString();
            txtfn.Text = myobj[1].ToString();
            txtln.Text = myobj[2].ToString();
            txtdob.Text = myobj[3].ToString();
            txtage.Text = myobj[4].ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I got new exception now. An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in WpfApp.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.